# Morphing pointclouds doesnt keep original position when returning in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am having an issue trying to get a pointcloud morph to work the way I want it to work, I have some font I am going to show and then morph into the pointcloud, but the issue is that each point forgets its original position and spawns randomly back to the geometry, it took me a while to get this right but if I can’t get the colours in the correct spot, it makes no sense to keep going with this project!
Any help would be amazing, even if it’s a reply to tell me it’s not possible, thank you!

Below is how the colours should look
[image]

Just a default text to see it working, I morphed the pointcloud into this, and then want to morph back

[image]

This is after morphing back into the pointcloud, the points are scattered randomly!

[image]

I followed a tutorial on Youtube, here is the code that makes it work

This is the code that makes it work, its put it inside its own group
[image]

Here is the outputs linked into its attribute
[image]

And here is the set position moving the points
[image]